# Group users by meta field, with name of meta field as group title

Tags: wp-query, users, user-meta

I'm creating a employee photo directory based off users from my site. I'm trying to add front end filtering for this query and I have it mostly working.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to sort the users by last name, department (custom field), or office location (custom field). Those of like departments and office locations would be grouped together under a heading of said department/location.

Everything is working with the exception of listing the department/location name, when using these filters, all the users are grouped and sorted by department/location as expected, but i need to return/echo the name of the department/location for each group of employees.

Here's how I'm currently querying and filtering

```
if (!isset($_GET["sortBy"])){
    $args = array('orderby' => 'display_name',);
} else {
    $sortBy = htmlspecialchars($_GET["sortBy"]);        
    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => $sortBy,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    );
}               

echo 'Sort By: <a href="?sortBy=first_name">First Name</a> // <a href="?sortBy=last_name">Last Name</a> // <a href="?sortBy=emp_dept">Department</a> // <a href="?sortBy=emp_office">Location</a> ';

echo '<ul class="photo_dir">';
    
$users = get_users($args); 

    foreach($users as $user){           
        if (empty($user->next_ad_int_user_disabled)){           
            
            $userlogin = $user->user_login ;
            $userID = $user->ID ;
            
            $regexCaptures = "/CN=([\w\s\\\\,]+),/";
            $manager = $user->emp_manager;
            preg_match($regexCaptures, $manager, $match);
            List($lastname, $firstname) = explode(',', str_replace("\\", "", $match[1]));
            $manager = $firstname . " " . $lastname;
            
            if (empty($user->emp_profile_pic)){             
                $profile_pic = 'http://www/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/logo-col-white-space.jpg';
            } else {
                $profile_pic = 'data:image/gif;base64,' . $user->emp_profile_pic;
            }
            
            if (empty($user->emp_mobile_phone )){               
                $mobile_phone = '';
            } else {
                $mobile_phone = '<span><i class="fa-solid fa-mobile-screen-button"></i> ' . $user->emp_mobile_phone . '</span>';
            }
            
            if (empty(get_field('vehicle_',$userID))){          
                $vehicle = '';
            } else {
                $vehicle = '<span><strong>Vehicle ID:</strong> ' . get_field('vehicle_',$userID) . '</span>';
            }
            
            echo '<li class="emp_profile" style="max-height:155px;">';
                echo '<button class="wp-colorbox-inline cboxElement" href="#inline_content_' . $userlogin . '" style="background-image: url(' . $profile_pic . ');">';
                    echo '<span>';
                        echo '<b style="font-size:14px;">' . $user->data->display_name . ' x' . $user->emp_office_ext . '</b><br/>';
                        echo '<em style="font-size:12px;white-space: nowrap; ">' . $user->emp_position . '</em>';
                    echo '</span>';
                echo '</button>';               
                
                echo '<div style="display:none;">';                             
                    echo '<div id="inline_content_' . $userlogin . '" class="emp_info">';
                        echo '<div class="left_half"><img name="Emp_photoHolder" src="' . $profile_pic . '"  border="0" alt="Please consult with HR to get your photo added to the intranet. A new picture may need to be taken." style="width:595px;">';
                        echo '</div><div class="right_half">';
                            echo '<h3>' . $user->data->display_name . '</h3>';
                            echo '<span style="text-align: center;font-style: italic;line-height: 10px; margin-bottom: 30px;">' . $user->emp_position . '</span>';
                            
                            echo '<span><strong>Department:</strong> ' . $user->emp_dept . '</span>';
                            echo '<span><strong>Manager:</strong> ' . $manager . '</span>';
                            echo '<i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i> ' . $user->emp_office;                                   
                            
                            
                            echo $mobile_phone;
                            echo $vehicle;
                            
                            echo '<div class="contact_info">';
                                echo '<div style="display: inline-block;width:59%;"><i class="fa-regular fa-paper-plane"></i> <a href="mailto:' . $user->user_email . '">' . $user->user_email . '</a></div>';
                                echo '<div style="display: inline-block;width:40%;"><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i> 360-565-3<b>' . $user->emp_office_ext . '</b></div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';                                         
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }


echo '</ul>';
        
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to return/echo the name of the department/location for each
> group of employees

That is actually a generic PHP/programming question, nonetheless, if you mean an output which looks like so:

```
Location/Department Name
- Employee/user
- Employee/user
- Employee/user

Location/Department Name
- Employee/user
- Employee/user
```

Then here's one way of accomplishing that:

1. Add this **above/before** the line `foreach($users as $user){`:

   ```php
   $current_group = ''; // The current location/department name.
   $sort_by_meta  = $args['meta_key'] ?? '';
   ```
2. Then add this **below/after** the line `if (empty($user->next_ad_int_user_disabled)){`:

   *Just modify the HTML to your own liking, but note that you need to [properly escape data](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/#h-guiding-principles) you're displaying to the user.*

   ```php
   // If sorting by location or department, and the current location/department has
   // changed, close the current UL, display the location name and open a new UL.
   if ( 'emp_office' === $sort_by_meta && $user->emp_office !== $current_group ) {
       $current_group = $user->emp_office;

       echo '</ul>';
       echo '<h3>' . esc_html( $current_group ) . '</h3>';
       echo '<ul class="photo_dir">';
   } elseif ( 'emp_dept' === $sort_by_meta && $user->emp_dept !== $current_group ) {
       $current_group = $user->emp_dept;

       echo '</ul>';
       echo '<h3>' . esc_html( $current_group ) . '</h3>';
       echo '<ul class="photo_dir">';
   }
   ```

Side Note: I don't know why did you call [`wp_reset_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/), but if you've created a [custom loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops) and you wanted to restore the `$post` global to the current post in the main query, then call `wp_reset_postdata()` and *not* `wp_reset_query()`.

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped, and I should add that, if the HTML is going to be exactly the same for both the location and department, you could combine the conditions into one `if` - `if ( $sort_by_meta && ( $user->$sort_by_meta !== $current_group ) && in_array( $sort_by_meta, array( 'emp_office', 'emp_dept' ) ) ) { $current_group = $user->$sort_by_meta; echo ... }` - see the full syntax-highlighted code [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/917343606cf6931b13faa2c1655ce2d9).